# HTML5 video player support time mark up and jumping programmatically

Tags: html5-video

I'm looking for a HTML5 video player that allows:

(i) (programmatically) making marks of the interesting segments on the time bar, so the users can quickly jump into that part. Something like YouTube's. Something looks like the following, where `#` is the interesting parts of the video.

```
-------#######---------##-------------##----------------
```

(ii) (programmatically) plays the video at a given time. So `javascript:play(5)` will skip to the 5th minute of the video.

Is there any such thing for free?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code cue points in this player will be useful. http://knowledge.kaltura.com/javascript-api-kaltura-media-players#HandlingCodeCuePoints
Also check the comparison of the players http://html5video.org/wiki/HTML5_Video_Player_Comparison